# Strange behavior when sending JSON over AJAX

Tags: javascript, json, ajax, rest, post

I am encountering some really strange behavior when sending JSON over AJAX.

JSON data:

```
data = {
    "name": "box1",
    "comment": ["fragile"],
    "type_A": [
        {
            "item": "1",
            "attr": [
                "big",
                "red"
            ]
        },
        {
            "item": "2",
            "attr": [
                "small",
                "red"
            ]
        },
    ],
    "type_B": [],
    "misc": {}
};
```

POST request:

```
$.ajax({
    url: url,
    type: "POST",
    // data: JSON.stringify(data),
    data: data,
    success: function (result) {
        console.log("inside success");
    },
    error: function (error) {
        console.log("inside error");
    }
});
```

If I pass in `data` here without `JSON.stringify()`, the empty fields `type_B` and `misc` get lost/stripped away. But if I do use `JSON.stringify()` then the backend cannot parse it properly without `JSON.parse()`. Is there a way to not strip away empty fields without doing a `JSON.parse()` in the backend?

I tried adding `contentType: "application/json"` and `dataType: "json"` to the request but didn't help.

Comment: What do you mean by "the backend cannot parse it properly"?

Comment: whats wrong in using JSON.parse in the backend ??

Comment: what is your backend? I think your problem is your backend!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jquery processes your data before sending and uses the request's post formdata instead of putting JSON in the body of the request.

To avoid this, use `processData: false` and `contentType: 'application/json'`:

```
$.ajax({
    url: url,
    type: "POST",
    processData: false,
    contentType: 'application/json',
    data: JSON.stringify(data),
    success: function (result) {
        console.log("inside success");
    },
    error: function (error) {
        console.log("inside error");
    }
});
```

Comment: "jQuery processes your data before sending" — It doesn't do that if you pass a string to `data`. This doesn't address the question which was about avoiding having to explicitly parse the data out of the JSON once it reached the server.

Answer (score 3):

What you have labeled "JSON data" is not JSON. It is a JavaScript object literal. It is part of JavaScript source code. It is not a JSON data file.

When you use jQuery's Ajax functions you can pass a few different things to `data`.

**If you pass it an object, then jQuery will Form URL Encode it.**

URL Encoded data has no standard way to represent anything other than a set of **flat** key=value pairs.

PHP introduced an extension which lets you express arrays and associative arrays by using square brackets in the key names. For example:

```
array[]=item1&array[]=item2
```

Each items in the array is represented by a copy of the key.

If you have no items, then there are no keys of that name.

If you use this method of encoding data then you cannot express empty arrays. The closest you could come would be to have an array containing a zero length string.

**If you pass it a string, then jQuery will just send it as is.**

Using `JSON.stringify` will convert your object to a string containing JSON data.

JSON is capable of expressing empty arrays.

PHP, however, will not automatically parse JSON formatted requests.

So…

> Is there a way to not strip away empty fields without doing a JSON.parse() in the backend?

No. There isn't. You either use a format which doesn't support empty fields, or you use a format which PHP won't automatically parse for you.

> I tried adding contentType: "application/json"

This tells the server that the data you are sending is encoded as JSON. If you are sending JSON then you should include this.

It doesn't alter the data you send. You need to encode the data as JSON yourself.

> and dataType: "json" to the request but didn't help.

This tells the server that you expect the response to the request to contain JSON. It also tells jQuery to ignore the content-type of the response and parse it as JSON whatever the server says it is.

It has no effect on the data you send.

Comment: So basically there is nothing I could do in this situation in the front end?

Comment: I can't really do `type_B: ['']`, that is what you are talking about right? Because it will fail in the backend as it checks if the incoming object is JSON, not string

Comment: Correct. "You either use a format which doesn't support empty fields, or you use a format which PHP won't automatically parse for you."

Comment: I am not using PHP by the way

Comment: It's Node.js backend

Comment: Maybe there is a way to turn JS object into JSON?

Comment: Node.js needs an explicit body parser no matter what format you use.

Comment: Turning a JS object into JSON is what you are doing here: `data: JSON.stringify(data)`

Comment: Seems like I could send a `JSON.stringify(data)` and set `processData: false`

Comment: @kevin_b — What about that post? To send JSON you need to use JSON.stringify … which you already mentioned in the question … and you should specify the content-type … which you mentioned in the question and I explained in the answer.

Comment: Setting `processData: false` is pointless. That's the default when you pass a string to `data`.

Comment: by default processData is set to True. See here: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Comment: @kevin_b — I'll rephrase: When passing a string to `data`, no processing will be done on it no matter what value `processData` has.